# Spring boot actuator breaks @AutoConfigureMockRestServiceServer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a class which builds multiple [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)s using [RestTemplateBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html):

```
private RestTemplate build(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
      .rootUri("http://localhost:8080/rest")
      .build();
}
```

For my test setup I use [@AutoConfigureMockRestServiceServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/client/AutoConfigureMockRestServiceServer.html) and mock responses using [MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer.html):

```
mockServerRestTemplateCustomizer.getServer()
  .expect(ExpectedCount.times(2),
        requestToUriTemplate("/some/path/{withParameters}", "withParameters"))
    .andRespond(withSuccess());
```

My test passes when I uncomment the `spring-boot-actuator` dependency in my pom and fails in the other scenario with the following message.

> Expected: /some/path/parameter
> Actual: http://localhost:8080/rest/pos/some/path/withParameters

I noticed by debugging through [MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer.html) that `spring-boot-actuator` applies a "[DelegateHttpClientInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/client/MetricsRestTemplateCustomizer.html)" for supporting their built in metrics for rest templates. However this creates a problem with the following code which I found in [RootUriRequestExpectationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/RootUriRequestExpectationManager.html):

```
public static RequestExpectationManager forRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate,
        RequestExpectationManager expectationManager) {
    Assert.notNull(restTemplate, "RestTemplate must not be null");
    UriTemplateHandler templateHandler = restTemplate.getUriTemplateHandler();
    if (templateHandler instanceof RootUriTemplateHandler) {
        return new RootUriRequestExpectationManager(((RootUriTemplateHandler) templateHandler).getRootUri(),
                expectationManager);
    }
    return expectationManager;
}
```

Because as mentioned above `spring-boot-actuator` registers a "[DelegateHttpClientInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/client/MetricsRestTemplateCustomizer.html)" which leads to the above code not recognizing the RootUriTemplateHandler and therefore not matching the request using [requestToUriTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/match/MockRestRequestMatchers.html#requestToUriTemplate-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

What am I missing here to get this working?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Spring Boot. Could you please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues), ideally with a minimal sample that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) pointed out, this seems to be a bug in Spring boot. I [created an issue with a sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25741).